# How to dynamic import not components in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

i'm hard stuck on a problem in next.js.

I have a page under app folder declared as 'use client', in this page i use a component also declared with 'use client'.
In this component i'm importing '**[slickgrid-react](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-react)**'.

In dev it works fine but when i try build, i'm getting the error **window is not defined**.

So i searched online and i've found out about dynamic imports at first it looked all good but it's not working well.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const SlickgridReact: any = dynamic(() => import("slickgrid-react").then((mod) => mod.SlickgridReact), {ssr: false});
const Formatters: any = dynamic(() => import("slickgrid-react").then((mod: any) => mod.Formatters), {ssr: false});
const Filters: any = dynamic(() => import("slickgrid-react").then((mod: any) => mod.Filters), {ssr: false});
const Aggregators: any = dynamic(() => import("slickgrid-react").then((mod: any) => mod.Aggregators), {ssr: false});
const FieldType: any = dynamic(() => import("slickgrid-react").then((mod: any) => mod.FieldType), {ssr: false});
const GroupTotalFormatters: any = dynamic(() => import("slickgrid-react").then((mod: any) => mod.GroupTotalFormatters), {ssr: false});
const SortComparers: any = dynamic(() => import("slickgrid-react").then((mod: any) => mod.SortComparers), {ssr: false});
const SortDirectionNumber: any = dynamic(() => import("slickgrid-react").then((mod: any) => mod.SortDirectionNumber), {ssr: false});
```

This was my first try but i've achieved next dynamic import is only for components and `Formatters, Filters, Aggregators`, for examples, are not components. In fact it throws me an error.

My second try was importing thoose in useEffect Hook as below:

```
const aggregators = useRef<any>(null);
const filters = useRef<any>(null);
const formatters = useRef<any>(null);
const sortComparers = useRef<any>(null);
const sortDirectionNumber = useRef<any>(null);
const groupTotalFormatters = useRef<any>(null);
const fieldType = useRef<any>(null);


useEffect(() => {
        let active = true;
        if (active) {
            const initImports = async () => {
                const { Aggregators, Filters, Formatters, SortComparers, SortDirectionNumber, GroupTotalFormatters, FieldType } = await import('slickgrid-react');
                aggregators.current = Aggregators;
                console.log(aggregators.current);
                filters.current = Filters;
                formatters.current = Formatters;
                sortComparers.current = SortComparers;
                sortDirectionNumber.current = SortDirectionNumber;
                groupTotalFormatters.current = GroupTotalFormatters;
                fieldType.current = FieldType;
            }
            initImports();
        }
        return () => {
            active = false;
        }
    }, []);
```

but again this didn't work thowing this error: **`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sumTotals')`**.

Where sumTotals is: **groupTotalFormatters.current.sumTotals**.

The thing i do not understand is why is he trying to ssr component import ever if i specified 'use client'.

Can someone help me please?

Already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543158/nextjs-dynamic-function-import-not-component) opened issue but for me is different, i need this not based on route and i must import diffrent things from the same package.

I tried also to keep the default import:

```
import {
    Aggregators, FieldType,
    Filters, Formatters, Grouping, GroupTotalFormatters,
    SlickDataView,
    SlickGrid,
    SlickgridReact,
    SlickgridReactInstance,
    SortComparers, SortDirectionNumber
} from "slickgrid-react";
```

But this is where everything begin.

I do not know how to solve that.

What should i do?